# How could I change user in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile to build my grid sge app and after configuring this file under root I need to change user, but when using command USER it just change default root before the container is build

Comment: Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After each layer in the dockerfile the user is changed back to root. If you want to run your container as a different user, create your user and the permissions in the dockerfile,

when you start your container for the first time, add the option --user  to change to the user you created in your dockerfile when you start the docker container.

for example,
`docker run -it --user nobody busybox`